Fullscreen does not fill the screen in SwiftUI
No matter what I do, I can't make it use the whole screen in landscape/portrait mode... any ideas?
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.purple
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

[

Your example works for me. You can also remove the .frame and the (deprecated) modifier .edgesIgnoringSafeArea and it still works.

works as in... you are seeing something different from my screenshot?

Because the screenshot is NOT fullscreen

Yes, full screen when I try it. But the time and network provider may be clues, it looks like the device might be locked in portrait orientation.

Can you show a screenshot? How come the same few lines of code don't work for me?

Actually, it's not full screen in portrait as well (it's just the app I started working on is supposed to be landscape)...

You accidentally removed the UILaunchScreen from the Info section of the project.
Bring it back and your current code is good to go.

